# Download Json file from URL with progressbar

Tags: c#, json, download, progress-bar, httpwebresponse

I need to download large json files from url. It uses post method, with parameter, username, password, etc.

As it takes quite long time, I try to put a progressbar, so users can see how far it has gone, and how much is left.

**Problem**

I am not able to retrieve the content length of the Json file from url before the download. Please see error commented in the code below. Any suggestions ?

```
public void downloadJson(string Url, string UserName, string Password, string FileDownload)
{
    HttpWebRequest httpRequest;
    HttpWebResponse httpResponse;
    int Size;

    var json = string.Format("{{\"user\":\"{0}\",\"pwd\":\"{1}\",\"DS\":\"KG\"}}", UserName, Password);

    httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
    httpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;

    httpRequest.ContentLength = json.Length;
    httpRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    httpRequest.Timeout = 600 * 60 * 1000;

    var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(json); // or UTF8

    using (var s = httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        s.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        s.Close();
    }

    httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
    Size = (int)httpResponse.ContentLength;
    Stream rs = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();

    //**********************************************
    //Here is the error
    //the below progress bar would never work
    //Because Size returned from above is always -1
    //**********************************************
    progressBar.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => progressBar.Maximum = Size));

    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(FileDownload))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
        int read;
        int position;

        using (rs)
        {
            while ((read = rs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                fs.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                position = (int)fs.Position;
                progressBar.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => progressBar.Value = position));
                Console.WriteLine ("Bytes Received: " + position.ToString());
            }
        }

        fs.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error could be here;

Size = (int)httpResponse.ContentLength;

I believe when you declared like 
 int Size;
You wanted to assign the integer datatype Size

But it seems like Size is not behaving like an integer datatype.

Try changing Size to something like siz and try it again.